# Convert PDF to image using python (pdf2image module)

Tags: python, numpy, pdf

I am using Python with pdf2image module to convert a PDF to image.

My Code :

```
import numpy as np
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('file.pdf')
print(pages)
```

I don't know why i am getting this errors

[image]

[image]

Comment: use the full path of the file

Comment: You are right @luigigi it works ! but this is not professional do you have an other solution ? i am using Windows 10 and VScode editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is due to the path ! you should put the absolute path starting from C:\ (windows)